# How do you test for a string parameter in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

I've got an issue where I'm trying to put multiple facebook pixels on a website which I've got working fine.  These pixels are put in through google tag manager.  The problem now is there's two instances of GTM on the site and now they're trying to add a facebook pixel through that instance too.  This is calling the same functions now twice and causing multiple pixel fires even though the functions are on two difference instances of GTM.

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', { 
    num_items: {{Quantity}},
    content_type: 'product',
    content_ids: ['{{DL - Event ID}}'],
    content_name: '{{DL - Event Name}} - {{DL - Event Detail - Purchase Event Detail}}',
    content_category: 'Order ID - {{Orderid}}',
    value: '{{DL - Purchase Revenue}}',
    currency: '{{Currency Lookup}}'
});
```

So I can't just check if function 'fbq' already exists because that's what fires all their functions, so what I need to look for is if the string 'Purchase' already exists, and my googling has only come up with the solution to see if a function exists.  Can anyone help me see is the string 'Purchase' exists as a parameter?  Thanks

Comment: Where do you need to check that condition? Inside the `fbq` or outside it?

Comment: It could probably be inside I just don't see how that would be done, but I'm open to anything.

Comment: if it's firing twice because of two separate pixels, and you only want to notify only one of them, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399994/4810109