# Facebook SDK init creating a second pixel

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, pixel

Two pixels are being initialized on my website even though I have only initialized one pixel. I've pin pointed the second pixel being initialized to the appId that is being used to initialize the Facebook SDK for Facebook login. How do I stop that second pixel from being initialized. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34889880) and [this](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10100525729830570), having multiple pixels on one webpage is not a good idea. Below are the details of what I am doing.

I am initializing a facebook pixel in my header using the standard facebook pixel code below

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '{pixel-id}');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={app-id}&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

This works fine and initializes the pixel fine. The issue is that when I initialize facebook login with my app ID, it creates another pixel, but this time it is with my app ID as the pixel ID. I am checking this through the pixel helper for facebook.

I initialize it with the following code:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
  FB.init({
    appId: '{app-id}',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: false,
    version: 'v2.12'
  });
```

Comment: That would presumably be the effect of `autoLogAppEvents: true`, I suppose?

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is that when I initialize facebook login with my app ID, it creates another pixel, but this time it is with my app ID as the pixel ID.

That would be the effect of

```
autoLogAppEvents: true,
```

in your FB.init call to initialize the SDK. Remove that, then the additional, unwanted pixel should be gone as well.